# X-editable ajax is not send for some ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, x-editable

I am using X-editable, when i am using id='firstname' in  then editable is not sending ajax request and when i change the id with other name then that is working fine..i don't know the reason or i am doing any mistake.please reply.

```
<a href="#" id="firstname"  date-url="<?php echo $profileupdateUrl ?>"  data-type="text"  data-title="Enter Lead Firstname"><?php echo $firstName; ?></a>

$('document').ready(function () {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';            
        $('#firstname').editable({
            url: "<?php echo $profileupdateUrl; ?>",
            success: function (response, newValue) {
                if (response.status == 'error') {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    return response.msg; //msg will be shown in editable form
                }
            }
        });
     });
```

Comment: do you use `id="firstname"` somewhere else, it could be a `id` conflict

Comment: @Yunhai thanks for reply....No there is no id conflict issue...now its working fine after clear the cache...both local and browser cache..